# Hiding or not producing axis lines inside first circular grid

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to create empty space inside the center circle of the radar chart. Ideally, I want the axis to start at 1 radius (the first circular line) or the stoke to be 0 for the first radius. Thank you for the help.

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-goldwasser-6hw0w?file=/src/charts/RadarChart.js

My current axis lines:

````
var axis = axisGrid
        .selectAll(".axis")
        .data(allAxis)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis");
      //Append the lines
      axis
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(maxValue) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(maxValue) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "#6299C8")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px");
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define `innerRadius` constant:

```js
const innerRadius = 30;
```

2. Build rScale accordingly:

```js
var rScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .range([innerRadius, radius])
  .domain([0, maxValue]);
```

3. Fix `x1` and `y1` of the radial lines:

```
axis
  .append("line")
  .attr("x1", function (d, i) {
    return rScale(0) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
  })
  .attr("y1", function (d, i) {
    return rScale(0) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
  })
  ...
```

4. Replace `1` with `0` in axis grig range:

```
axisGrid
  .selectAll(".levels")
  .data(d3.range(0, cfg.levels + 1).reverse())
  ...
```

See the result in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-wing-fvdss?file=/src/charts/RadarChart.js:6174-6266).

Comment: Happy to help :) Please mark my answer as correct